# Woocommerce display multiple error messages/notifications

Tags: php, wordpress, notifications, woocommerce, shopping-cart

I have a function that checks two minimum and maximum cart quantities for 2 different item categories - one's min max quantities depend on the number items present in the cart of the other item category - and also adds an item automatically for not logged in customers. How can I suppress 'item removed, undo' messages and make sure 'all' my warning are displayed? I've given the code below and any improvements on that also appreciated.

```
function check_total() {
// Only run in Cart or Checkout pages
if( is_cart() || is_checkout() ) {

    global $woocommerce, $product;
    $total_quantity = 0;
    $total_squantity = 0; //snacks 
    $display_notice = 1;
    $display_snotice = 1;
    $i = 0;

    //loop through all cart products
    foreach ( $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents as $product ) {
        // See if any product is from the breakfast or meals category or not
        if ( has_term( 'meals', 'product_cat', $product['product_id'] ) || has_term( 'breakfast', 'product_cat', $product['product_id'] ) ) {
            $total_quantity += $product['quantity'];
        }
        if ( has_term( 'snacks', 'product_cat', $product['product_id'] )) {
            $total_squantity += $product['quantity'];
        }       
    }

    // Set up the acceptable meal totals.
    $acceptable_totals = array(8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24);
    // Acceptable snacks totals
    $acceptable_stotals = array(0, 1, 2, 3, 4);

    foreach($acceptable_totals as $total_check) {
        if ( $total_check == $total_quantity ) { $display_notice = 0; } 
    }

    foreach($acceptable_stotals as $total_scheck) {
        if ( $total_scheck == $total_squantity ) { $display_snotice = 0; } 
    }

    foreach ( $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents as $product ) {
        if ( has_term( 'meals', 'product_cat', $product['product_id'] ) || has_term( 'breakfast', 'product_cat', $product['product_id'] ) ) {
            if( $display_notice == 1 && $i == 0 ) {
                // Display error message
                wc_print_notice( sprintf( 'Whoa, you need to order 8-12 meals (1 cooler) or 20-24 meals (2 coolers). Give it another shot!<br />', $total_quantity),'error' );
            }
            $i++;
        }

    }

    //Adjust snacks to match the meal quantities
    if ((($total_quantity == 8 ) || ($total_quantity == 20 ) ) && ($total_squantity > 4)){
            wc_print_notice( sprintf( 'Sorry dude, your bag can hold only 4 snack items...<br />', $total_squantity),'error' );
        }
        else if ((($total_quantity == 9 ) || ($total_quantity == 21 ) ) && ($total_squantity > 3)){
            wc_print_notice( sprintf( 'Sorry dude, your bag can hold only 3 snack items...<br />', $total_squantity),'error' );
        }
        else if ((($total_quantity == 10 ) || ($total_quantity == 22 ) ) && ($total_squantity > 2)){
            wc_print_notice( sprintf( 'Sorry dude, your bag can hold only 2 snack items...<br />', $total_squantity),'error' );
        }
        else if ((($total_quantity == 11 ) || ($total_quantity == 23 ) ) && ($total_squantity > 1)){
            wc_print_notice( sprintf( 'Sorry dude, your bag can hold only 1 snack item...<br />', $total_squantity),'error' );
        }
        else if ((($total_quantity == 12 ) || ($total_quantity == 24 ) ) && ($total_squantity > 0)){
            wc_print_notice( sprintf( 'Sorry dude, your bag(s) do not have enough space for snacks...<br />', $total_squantity),'error' );
        }

    // set our flag to be false until we find a product in that category
    $cat_check = false;

    // check each cart item for cooler bags category
    foreach ( $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents as $product ) {
        if ( has_term( 'cooler-bags', 'product_cat', $product['product_id'] )) {
            $cat_check = true;
            break;
        }       
    }

    // if a product in the cart is in our category, do something
    if ( $cat_check ) {
    // we have the category, do what we want
    }
    else {
        if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        //do nothing
        }
        else {
            // select ID
            $product_id = 148;
            WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id );
            // Display notification
            wc_print_notice( __( 'We just added a cooler bag to your order as you seem to be new around here. Not new? <a href="/my-account">Click here to login</a>', 'woocommerce' ), 'notice' );
        }
    }   
}
 }
```

Comment: Managed to remove the item removed message using CSS. '.woocommerce-cart .woocommerce-message {display: none !important;}'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to remove the item removed message using CSS. '.woocommerce-cart .woocommerce-message {display: none !important;}'.